# В чём отличия между agg и aggregate в pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

В чём отличия между указанными двумя функциями? Их описания полностью идентичны. Это синонимы?

[aggregate](http://aggregate)

[agg](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html#pandas.DataFrame.agg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Это синонимы :](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/frame.py#L4545)

```
def aggregate(self, func, axis=0, *args, **kwargs):
    axis = self._get_axis_number(axis)

    # TODO: flipped axis
    result = None
    if axis == 0:
        try:
            result, how = self._aggregate(func, axis=0, *args, **kwargs)
        except TypeError:
            pass
    if result is None:
        return self.apply(func, axis=axis, args=args, **kwargs)
    return result

agg = aggregate  # <------------- !!!
```

Проверка:

```
In [3]: pd.DataFrame.agg is pd.DataFrame.aggregate
Out[3]: True

In [4]: id(pd.DataFrame.agg) == id(pd.DataFrame.aggregate)
Out[4]: True
```